# Issue with sorting and creating map using java8

Tags: java, java-stream

i have a code like these

```
@Data
public class person{
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  int orderNum;
}

List<person> personList = new ArrayList<person>();
```

i am trying to sort object and trying get map based on order number.

i wrote a logic these this and didn't work for me

```
Map<String, String> xza = personList.stream()
  .sorted(Comparator.comparing(refDataDto::getOrderNum))
  .collect(Collectors.toList())
  .stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(refDataDto::getFirstName, refDataDto::getastName));
```

Comment: [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)): “*There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the Map returned.*” This includes that you can not assume the map to maintain insertion order. Use `Collectors.toMap(refDataDto::getFirstName, refDataDto::getastName, …, LinkedHashMap::new)` instead. Besides that, there’s no sense in inserting `.collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()` in the stream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sorting a list according to the order number, collecting it into a list, creating a stream from the list and then collecting the stream to an unsorted map. Maps don't, by default, preserve the order in which the key-value pairs are inserted.

What you need is a [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), but since there is not a ready made collector helper for it, [you have to set it up manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52975256/collect-stream-of-entryset-to-linkedhashmap) (and you don't need to collect the data to a list in between):

Also, since you are working on streams containing `Person` objects, the lambdas need to refer to the `Person` class, not `refDataDto`.

```
Map<String, String> xza = personList.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getOrderNum))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Person::getFirstName,
            Person::getLastName,
            (v1, v2) -> {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Key conflict");
            },
            LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Answer (score 2):

`Collectors.toMap(key,value)`, will by default create a `HashMap`, which is unordered.  You have to use a `LinkedHashMap` to order it in the same order of elements that were inserted in.

Also, `.collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()` is not useful. `sorted` would have given you a sorted stream, and on top of it, you are converting it to a list and then back to stream, so it is useless.

So, try `Collectors.toMap` overloaded method with 4 parameters instead of 2: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-

```
Map<String, String> xza = personList.stream()
  .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getOrderNum))
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(
    Person::getFirstName,
    Person::getastName,
    (u, v) -> {
      throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Duplicate key %s", u));
    },
    LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: You have copied the Java 8 version of the merge function which has a bug. `u` is *not* the key. Besides that, I consider `String.format("Duplicate key %s", u)` a horrible way to express exactly the same as `"Duplicate key " + u`. The latter is easier to read *and* way more efficient.